# EfficientAdapter and grabbing text of item clicked

Tags: android

For EfficientAdapter What code I need to use under onListItemClick to get text of selected item?
I tried:

```
str=(String) ((TextView)l.getItemAtPosition(position)).getText()
```

But this only brings CastException, since it fetches the LinearLayout view holding the textview and imageview (see code [here](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/List14.html))

Please help!

Some of the code:

```
public class Bookmarks extends ListActivity {
public static Typeface mFace;
public EfficientAdapter eff;

private static class EfficientAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public EfficientAdapter(Context context) {
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return DAT.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_text, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
            holder.text.setTypeface(mFace);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.text.setText(DAT[position]);

        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView text;
    }
}

public Object getItem(int position) { 
    return position; 
}

public void onResume(Bundle icicle) {
    eff.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    //////////CRASHES on next line!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
TextView tv = (TextView) l.getItemAtPosition(position);
    String str = tv.getText().toString();

}


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    eff = (new EfficientAdapter(this));
    setListAdapter(eff);
    registerForContextMenu(getListView());
}
```

}

Comment: It would help if you'd post the complete code of your click handler, especially the class and function definitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't really enough information in your question (see my comment above), but here's a guess at an answer:

First, `getText()` is [documented](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#getText%28%29) to return a CharSequence, not a String. It **might** return a String, but you don't know that it does. So it would be safer to write:

```
str = ((TextView)l.getItemAtPosition(position)).getText().toString()
```

Second, if that doesn't work, try breaking down that statement so you can get a better idea of where the exception is coming from. Something like this, perhaps, might be clearer:

```
TextView tv = (TextView) l.getItemAtPosition(position);
str = tv.getText().toString();
```

**EDIT** based on your update:

1) If you're going to implement `onListItemClick`, be sure that you begin the method by calling up to the base class, as shown below.

2) **Here's the problem:** (I realized this after copying and pasting in a different example, which I think won't be necessary now): [ListView.getItemAtPosition](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#getItemAtPosition%28int%29) doesn't return a View at all; it returns an item from your Adapter (a Cursor, an array entry, whatever.) To get the TextView, you need to use `findViewById`, or better still, your ViewHolder. I *think* this will work:

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
    TextView tv = holder.text;
    String str = tv.getText().toString();
}
```

If you're still having problems, please copy and paste the traceback for the exception that you're getting.

Comment: Thanks a lot! looks like a good solution. I went for the easy way. I created a public String array that just needed the position.