# How to change background color of a listitem

Tags: android, xml

I'm trying to change the color of some of the items in a list but not all off them.
Im using a adaptor to incorperate the list so that it is show when i press a button.
Now i cant figure out where I can get to the attributes (like background color) of the list item.

The code looks like this

> public void visskema(View view)
>       {

```
    Calendar date =Calendar.getInstance();
    /*redigerer for offset*/
    long oldtime =date.getTimeInMillis();
    long newtime= oldtime +((long)offsetuger*7*1000*3600*24);
    date.setTimeInMillis(newtime);
    int weekofyear= date.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
    int dayofmonth= date.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    int month=date.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1;
    int year=date.get(Calendar.YEAR);

    Vector<Skemabrik> aktuelskema =webservicegetskemauge(username,domain,dayofmonth,month, year,weekofyear);
    Vector<Skemabrik> sortetskema=sortskema(aktuelskema);
    Vector<Skemabrik> endeligtskema=padskema(sortetskema);
    if(endeligtskema.size()>0)
    {
        String[] fag =new String[endeligtskema.size()];
        for(int i=0;i<endeligtskema.size();i++)
        {
            Skemabrik brik =endeligtskema.get(i);
            String temp =brikToString(brik);    
            fag[i]=temp;
        }
        ListView lv = new ListView(this); 
        //final TextView citytext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.CITY);
        lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,fag)); 

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
                //  System.out.println("bøh" + listtext);
                setContentView(R.layout.skemauge);



                //  der skal sætttes billedet med de to knapper city og country og udfyldes værdi for country og city
            }
        });
        setContentView(lv);
    }
    else{
        setContentView(R.layout.skemauge);
        TextView Eugenummer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ugenummer);  
        Eugenummer.setText("Du har ingen timer i denne uge");
    }
}
```

if anybody could tell me how and where to get the the textview in the adaptor so i can change the background color i would appreciate it :) (im rather new at android :D)

Answer (score 1):

You have to implement your own custom list adapter and override `getView` method.
You could refer to [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4523614/efficientadapter-and-grabbing-text-of-item-clicked)

Comment: after trying for a few days im not sure its getview i want to change, I want to set the color before the list is displayed. Do i get it rigth when i think getview is used when i pick items in the list ?

Comment: getView is invoked every time list item draws himself, means on listview show, on listview scroll etc. So if you'll define your color here it will be set just before every list item displaying.